# Making a WIndow SQL query to a R studio code

Tags: sql, r, tidyverse

**Question**

I want to convert the created SQL into an R studio where the 2 calculations will be made. I can make a part but I don't understand the combination yet.

Code:

```sql
select
    f1.ClubName, f1.Percwaarde, f2.Percpunten
from
    (select 
         f.ClubName, sum(w.waarde) * 100.0 / sum(sum(w.waarde)) over() PercWaarde
     from 
         fact f 
     join 
         waarde w on w.WDID = f.WDID
     group by 
         f.clubname) f1 
inner join 
    (select 
         f.ClubName, sum(u.p) * 100.0 / sum(sum(u.p)) over() Percpunten
     from 
         fact f 
     join 
         uitslag u on u.StandID = f.StandID
     group by 
        f.clubname) f2 on f2.ClubName = f1.ClubName
```

**Data**

The SQL data has been retrieved from a database. But with the R code I am going to use an Excel file. so it can be retrieved from the data frame DF.

This is the code I have:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  summarize(tot = sum(Waarde)) %>% 
  transmute(Team, Perc = tot/sum(tot) *100)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution here will be to load the table via the DBI package. That way you can keep your SQL code intact and not have to recreate it using dplyr.

```
library(DBI)
driver <- dbDriver("[your driver]")
con <- dbConnect(driver, host = '[your host]', port = '[your port]',  user = '[your user]', password = '[your password]', dbname = '[your dbname]')

df <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0(
  'select
    f1.ClubName, f1.Percwaarde, f2.Percpunten
from
    (select 
         f.ClubName, sum(w.waarde) * 100.0 / sum(sum(w.waarde)) over() PercWaarde
     from 
         fact f 
     join 
         waarde w on w.WDID = f.WDID
     group by 
         f.clubname) f1 
inner join 
    (select 
         f.ClubName, sum(u.p) * 100.0 / sum(sum(u.p)) over() Percpunten
     from 
         fact f 
     join 
         uitslag u on u.StandID = f.StandID
     group by 
        f.clubname) f2 on f2.ClubName = f1.ClubName
    '))
```